# Hashtable using struct

Tags: c

I am working on a hashtable, But did not get too far. My question is how can i set the table to size. (read the description below for clarification).

this is what i am supposed to do :

```
/**
 * Create a new instance of struct hashStorage and return it. It sets the size of the
 * table to be of length "size" which will be the number of the entries in the hash. It takes also an
 * argument to specify the format of the order printed to an output stream. If myHash parameter
 * is NULL then this means that the hash should be a linked list. When myHash is NULL the size
 * parameter should be ignored.
 */

struct hashStorage {
    int    (*funcHash)  (int);
    void   (*printItem) (struct order *, FILE *);
    struct onode**      table;
    int    size;
};

struct hashStorage* createHash(int size, int (*myHash)(int),void(*printOrder)(struct order *, FILE *))
{
     struct hashStorage* hashList = (struct hashStorage*) malloc(sizeof(struct hashStorage));

     hashList->table;

    if(myHash == NULL)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
     return hashList;
}
```

if somebody could explain me giving and example will be a great help.

Comment: Why did you tag this with C# when it looks like C/C++?

Comment: that was just a typo, ddn mean to tag it to c#

Comment: perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but why can't you just do `hashList->table = malloc(size * sizeof(struct onode*));`

Comment: it will cause and compiler errors because void cannot be assigned to onode**

Comment: then you are compiling C source as C++. Add a type cast `...=(struct onode**)malloc(...)`

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk should have thought about that, thank you.

Comment: "Add a type cast" -- Wrong/bad advice. C and C++ are different languages. In C the cast isn't necessary. In C++ use `new`.

Comment: @JimBalter, without type cast, C compiler tend to give errors. I agree its not a necessity.

Comment: No, it does not "tend to give errors" -- the language standard says that `void*` is convertible to any (non-function) pointer type. There are many many comments here about SO saying not to cast `malloc`, as you will learn when you get more experience.

Comment: In C++ you have to type cast (void *). Anyhow, this is not the point. The OP does not provide enough information.

Comment: Does the table array need to be allocated as well ? (i.e `hashList->table = (onode **)malloc(sizeof(onode)*size);` if `myHash == NULL` ?

Comment: "Add a typecast"? That's **horrible** advice! Either compile as C (and remove the typecast) or compile as C++ and use the `new` keyword (and the C++ tag).

Answer (score 0):

You seek to set the value for the object you have allocated. The obstacles you face are:

1. For some reason you want to merge the linked list and hashtable data structures? That's folly, but whatever...
2. `malloc` doesn't necessarily return a pointer to an object; it might return `NULL`. You need to check that before proceeding.
3. The object you assign the return value of `malloc` to is not the object you seek to assign to, so `hashList = ...` won't work; you need to use `*hashlist = ...` or `hashlist->member = ...`.

Here's how I would write this code:

```
typedef size_t hash_fn(int);
typedef void print_fn(struct order *, FILE *);

struct hash_table {
    size_t       size;
    hash_fn      *hash_function;
    print_fn     *print_function;
    struct onode *item[];
};

struct hash_table *create_hash_table(size_t size, hash_fn *hash_function, print_fn *print_function)
{
    if (hash_function == NULL)
    {
        /* This should give you enough to implement your linked list;
         * use hash_table->item[0] as your item and hash_table->item[1]
         * as your link. */
        size = 2;
    }

    struct hash_table *hash_table = malloc(sizeof *hash_table
                                         + size * sizeof *hash_table->table);
    if (hash_table == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    *hash_table = (struct hash_table) { .size = size
                                      , .hash_function = hash_function
                                      , .print_function = print_function };

    return hash_table;
}
```